# Getting BLOB file from oracle in Windows Form C#

Tags: asp.net, winforms, oracle11g

i'm a noob in C# and tried to create project to download blob file from oracle in win forms and save the file in local downloads folder.

here's my code

```
string tempDir = "\\\\NB17-KP-239\\Downloads\\";
                        for (int index = 0; index < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++index)
                        {

                            string oradbConString = "Data Source = localhost; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = homeuser; Password = admin;";
                            OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection(oradbConString);
                            oraCon.Open();

                            string path;
                            using (oraCon)
                            {
                                using (OracleCommand comOra = oraCon.CreateCommand())
                                {
                                    comOra.CommandText = "select id,name,contenttype from blob_sample where id = 3";
                                    //comOra.Parameters.Add("Id", dataTable.Rows[index]["id"]);

                                    OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = comOra.ExecuteReader();
                                    oracleDataReader.Read();
                                    OracleBlob oracleBlob = oracleDataReader.GetOracleBlob(1);

                                    using (TempFileCollection tempFileCollection = new TempFileCollection(tempDir, false))
                                    {
                                        path = tempFileCollection.AddExtension("file", true);
                                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[oracleBlob.Length];
                                        int count = oracleBlob.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oracleBlob.Length));
                                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                                        fileStream.Close();
                                    }
                                }
                                oraCon.Close();
                            }
```

what's wrong with that?
if i try a simple code to select file and show it on label,the code is working fine.
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: the problem was that I chose element (1) in the `GetOracleBlob` array while the correct one was (0).

```
string tempDir = string tempDir = @"D:\Test";
                        for (int index = 0; index < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++index)
                        {
                            //this.AppendText("download start : " + reqBy + " < " + appBy + "\r\n");

                            string oradbConString = "Data Source = localhost; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = homeuser; Password = admin;";
                            
                            OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection(oradbConString);
                            oraCon.Open();

                            string path;
                            using (oraCon)
                            {
                                using (OracleCommand comOra = oraCon.CreateCommand())
                                {

                                    comOra.CommandText = "select data from blob_sample where id = 4";

                                    OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = comOra.ExecuteReader();
                                    oracleDataReader.Read();
                                    OracleBlob oracleBlob = oracleDataReader.GetOracleBlob(0);

                                    using (TempFileCollection tempFileCollection = new TempFileCollection(tempDir, false))
                                    {
                                        path = tempFileCollection.AddExtension("file", true);
                                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[oracleBlob.Length];
                                        int count = oracleBlob.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oracleBlob.Length));
                                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                                        fileStream.Close();
                                    }
                                }
                                oraCon.Close();
                            }
```